# Getline only reads the first word

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I'm new to C++ and I couldn't solve this problem. `getline(cin, string)` keeps reading only the first word of the line.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string commitToFile, newTextFile, loadedText;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter some text to save to a file." << endl;
    getline(cin, commitToFile);
    cout << "Enter a file name. Please do not use spaces." << endl;
    cin >> newTextFile;
    newTextFile.append(".tf");
    cout << "Saving..." << endl;
    ofstream saveText(newTextFile); //.tf stands for textfile
    if (!saveText) {
        cout << "Error!";
        return(0);
    }
    saveText << commitToFile << endl;
    saveText.close();
    cout << "Saved!" << endl;

    //opening the file
    cout << "Loading file..." << endl;
    ifstream loadText(newTextFile);
    loadText >> loadedText;
    loadText.close();
    cout << loadedText;
    return(0);
}
```

The entered text is then saved into a file, but when I try to read the file, only one word is saved, and this is the first word. I'm not sure if this has been asked before, but I've tried using the advanced search to no avail.

Comment: Where do you open the file? Where do you write to the file? *How* do you open/write the file? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Try removing `cin.ignore()`. It removes the first letter of the `commitToFile` string.

Comment: I've updated it, it now includes all the file opening and stuff. I'm trying to create a file system where you can actually create folders and text files which can be stored in folders. This is actually the text file bit, and I for some reason could not get more than one word to be saved.

Comment: This isn't a program that we can run. Please follow the link that Joachim gave you and read the instructions!

Comment: The reason why I kept     cin.ignore()    there was because it was skipping the getline as getline was reading the    \n    left on the input buffer. That caused getline to simply take the remaining    \n    and skip actual input.

Comment: BTW, how do you verify the file only contains the first word? A program you wrote, or visual inspection (e.g. in a text editor)?

Comment: It was a visual inspection. I went to the home directory and opened the file I created in TextEdit. (oh, and the reason I didn't use .txt for the extension but .tf was because it was quite confusing with the other stuff in that folder were saved as .txt files, and also to avoid confusion.)

Comment: It's missing includes and includes an obsolete `cstdlib` header.

Comment: When I add the missing `#include`s (`<string>`, `<fstream>`, `<iostream>`) and declarations (`string commitToFile, newTextFile;`), the code works for me on VS2010. Can you detail how your setup differs? Ideally provide the sample input.

Comment: I thought    #include <cstdlib>    did the trick? If I'm not mistaken, the declarations Angew specified are all included in the c++ standard library.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I missed the declaration of the strings. Also, I use Xcode to compile my programs. Sample input would be any text, for example, "lorem ipsum" or something like that.

Comment: @HarryCodes `<cstdlib>` is not "the C++ standard library." It's *one of the headers of the C++ standard library:* the C++ equivalent of C's `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Re the latest edit: of course `loadedText` will end on the first space&mdash;you're using `>>` to extract it, which stops on whitespace.

Comment: Okay, I have a correction to point out. I performed a visual inspection once more on the same file, the exact same text I entered was there. Now, my only problem resides in not being able to read the file into a string as a whole. I've seen this somewhere, but I could not understand the answer. It would be great if somebody could simplify/break down/suggest a new answer. Thank you all so much for your help!

Comment: @Angew I just refreshed my page. Is there a way to change the delimiter on the    >>    from a whitespace to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `>>` to extract the string. `>>` for strings normally stops on whitespace.

To read a whole line, do what you're already doing with `cin`—use `getline`:

```
cout << "Loading file..." << endl;
ifstream loadText(newTextFile);
getline(loadText, loadedText);
loadText >> loadedText;
loadText.close();
cout << loadedText;
```